# Hard drive life monitor?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Looking for a tool that can tell me when my hard drives are expected to die. Can anyone recommend a (preferably) free one?

Comment: You mean other than SMART?

Comment: @fixer1234 No, I didn't even know about SMART at the time of this writing. I think I had a ticking harddrive and I just wanted to know if it was about to crap out or not (it's actually still working almost 5 years later!)

Comment: Try one of the recommended SMART tools to verify that your drive has the feature (not all older drives did, especially ones that were small by today's standards).  If not, update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd thoroughly recommend [HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com/) - it has a benchmarking capability, access to SMART information and other device information, and a low-level surface scan (to detect bad sectors etc)

Answer (score 3):

You need a SMART monitor, a program that displays the health statistics of the hard drives.

[**GSmartControl**](http://gsmartcontrol.berlios.de/home/index.php/en/Home) runs on Windows 7 and is free.

Comment: Link is dead now.

Answer (score 1):

[Hard Disk Sentinel](http://www.hdsentinel.com/) works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there's [DiskSmartView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/disk_smart_view.html) from NirSoft. I also highly recommend [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) utilities.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try [HDDLife](http://www.hddlife.com/). It's quite useful tool for server monitoring.
You can get for free only trial on offical site, but you can google it and find some patched version on some public torrent tracker.