# How do I troubleshoot a slow hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, troubleshooting, diagnostic

My computer is suffering of slow-downs and I'm not surprised (it's around 6
years old). Here's what I've verified:

1. They are not very frequent (only a couple of times a day).
2. When they happen a single application will hang for 10-60 seconds, while the rest don't hang but also get slow.
3. Even as it is happening, the CPU usage stays low.
4. It happens to applications (such as text editor, firefox, skype).
5. It never happens to some applications (such as games) which I use for hours under heavy CPU load.

Also of note:

6. The Graphics card and PSU are new (around a year).
7. Though I have a decent amount of software installed right now, this was happening even right after I reinstalled Windows.
8. This HDD has been through many partinioning schemes, and a few heavy operations (such as moving around 200GB of data).

Because of the above, I am already 70% sure the problem is with the hard
drive. Before I replace it, however, I want to rule out other less likely
possibilities (such as RAM, software, or PSU).

I don't have the money to replace the entire box right now, but I can easily
replace one of the components.

I've read several questions (such as
[this one](https://superuser.com/q/260043/6371)) which give general guidance on
troubleshooting an unknown issue, that is **not** what I'm looking for here.

My main question is:
**What tests or benchmarks can I run to verify I have a problematic hard drive?**
I don't need to solve this problem, I am content with just making sure it's the
hard drive.

I could borrow a newer hard drive from a friend and see if it gets better. A
positive result would rule out all other components, but it wouldn't rule out a
software issue (since this new hard drive won't have any of the software I use
daily).

*Running on Windows/Linux.*

Comment: As it stands this question is MUCH too vague.  What specifically have to tried already, and where are you getting stuck?  There's no way for us to tell you how to be 100% confident in your diagnosis.  If you want to test a replacement drive, get a hard drive and duplicate your drive onto it.  You can find out how to do that searching here on SU.  Or take it to someone who can do it for you (like a computer shop).

Comment: If you are just looking for a list of HDD Diagnostics software, please clarify that by editing your question, and include a list of which ones you've tried already, and why the many related questions on SU were of no help.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: if diagnostics don't report any problems with the hard drive but you want to confirm that the new drive exhibits the same issue, you can clone your drive's contents onto a new one--in which case, you will have the same software on both drives.

Comment: @techie007 I am looking for anything that verifies the HDD is getting old. Yes, HDD diagnostic is one thing (and I haven't tried any yet).

Comment: [Hard drive life monitor?](http://superuser.com/questions/114476/hard-drive-life-monitor), [Detecting/diagnosing drive “pauses”. Any good tools out there?](http://superuser.com/questions/378537/detecting-diagnosing-drive-pauses-any-good-tools-out-there), [How to check the health of a hard drive](http://superuser.com/questions/171195/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-hard-drive), [What is the best hardware diagnostic for a PC](http://superuser.com/questions/104235/what-is-the-best-hardware-diagnostic-for-a-pc?lq=1)

Comment: @techie007 The answers to those questions you linked to don't seem to be very *comprehensive*... :\

Comment: @Deltik Just because they are not "comprehensive" doesn't mean they aren't asking the same thing. The op's question is "What tests or benchmarks can I run to verify I have a problematic hard drive?" How is that question different from the ones I've listed there?

Comment: @techie007 I still think that [Bruce](http://superuser.com/users/6371/bruce-connor) did the right thing.  See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138198/188803

Comment: @techie007 I tried clarifying what you asked for in my edit. I hadn't tried any tools before asking this question, I didn't even know any, and SU is usually my first stop when tackling something I don't know :). I did search around first, but I hadn't found any of those questions because I was restricting the search to the [troubleshoot] and [hard-drive] tags (which seemed to me like the bare minimum).

Comment: Defragmentation perhaps?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Checking the [S.M.A.R.T. attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) is a useful at-a-glance first step to identifying hard drive issues.

### Accessing S.M.A.R.T. Attributes

You can view S.M.A.R.T. attributes on Windows using third-party tools such as [GSmartControl](http://gsmartcontrol.sf.net/).

On macOS, you can use [Disk Utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Utility), though it isn't very verbose.  You can [install `smartctl` from the package `smartmontools`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/135566) to access the S.M.A.R.T. attributes using the command line.

On Linux, the command `smartctl -a /dev/hda` (from the package `smartmontools`) gives S.M.A.R.T. information about a hard drive, where `/dev/hda` is replaced with the device in question.  [GNOME Disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks) (`gnome-disks` from the package `gnome-disk-utility`, previously known as `palimpsest`) is a graphical utility that can give some more advice about the condition of your hard drive.

[image: [palimpsest shows a bad HDD.]]

#### Understanding S.M.A.R.T. Attributes

*Here are some attributes that are relevant and worth noting.  A larger list can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes).*

A non-zero **Read Error Rate** (ID 1) indicates a problem with either the disk surface or the read/write heads.

The **Throughput Performance** (ID 2) is the average efficiency of the disk.  If the value drops below the threshold, something may be wrong with the disk.

A high **Spin-Up Time** (ID 3) (recorded in milliseconds) may indicate that the hard drive is having trouble spinning up.

An increasing **Reallocated Sectors Count** (ID 5) means that areas on the hard drive are failing in integrity, and data had to be moved.  This causes performance decreases when sectors are being remapped, but it may be more serious in that the hard drive is about to fail.

A low **Seek Time Performance** (ID 8) is a sign of a mechanical issue with the magnetic heads.

The **Spin Retry Count** (ID 10) goes up when a spin-up fails.  If this happens, input/output operations are queued until the hard drive can spin normally, which causes slowdowns.  More importantly, though, if the hard drive has to retry spinning up, it's a sign of imminent failure.

A non-zero **Reported Uncorrectable Errors** (ID 187) count means that that number of sectors could not be corrected by hardware error correction. Here's a sign of old age.

The **Current Pending Sector Count** (ID 197) is the number of sectors waiting to be remapped.  This indicates old age of the hard drive.

## HDD Benchmarks

[image: [Palimpsest HDD Read Test]]

If there's a certain location in the hard drive that is getting poor performance (maybe where frequently used information is stored), hard drive read benchmarks can help confirm this.  Above is a screenshot of a hard drive benchmark using `palimpsest`, now known as [GNOME Disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks) (`gnome-disks`).

If you prefer to do command line benchmarks on Linux, you can combine multiple options:

- **`hdparm`** (from the package `hdparm`)

  - `hdparm -t /dev/hda` — Buffered sequential read test on `/dev/hda`
  - `hdparm -T /dev/hda` — Cached sequential read test on `/dev/hda`
- **`dd`** (from the package `coreutils`)

  - `dd if=/dev/hda of=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1024` — Sustain a read from the beginning of `/dev/hda` for `1GiB` using a block size of `1MiB`
- **`ioping`** (from the package `ioping`)

  - `ioping -R /dev/hda` — Random read test on `/dev/hda`

On Windows, you can use tools like [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/) to do hard drive benchmarks.

On macOS, you can use tools like [Blackmagic Disk Speed Test](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id425264550) to do hard drive benchmarks.

Comment: To add to this answer: reallocated sectors will cause slowdowns whenever you try to access the address that was remapped. The more reallocated sectors, the more likely it is that you'll notice the slowdown as the hard drive seeks to a different part of the disk surface to read from the remapped address.

Comment: A non-zero Raw Read Error Rate does *not* necessarily indicate a problem with the drive, see my explanation on http://superuser.com/questions/393257/brand-new-seagate-hdd-has-high-raw-read-error-rate/442798#442798.

Comment: The Spin Up Time is reported as a raw value of 5458, and the Power On Time is 13477. Is that a problem? 5 seconds sounds like a lot.

Comment: 5.448 seconds for Spin-Up Time? That may seem like a long time, but it could be in the ballpark of normal.  Source: [Western Digital Scorpio ML40 Optimized Spinup Feature](http://www.wdc.com/en/library/portable/2579-001116.pdf).  561.5-ish days for Power-On Hours?  To me, it doesn't mean much because I leave my SATA devices powered on almost 24/7.

Comment: Pretty thorough.  Usually, I just run chkdsk, though.  Either it solves the issue, or I get a new harddrive.  If it doesn't solve the issue, the drive is typically 5-10 years old, anyway.  I figure, these things break.

Comment: Great answer with plenty of detail. Helped me decide to get a new hard drive ASAP. Thanks.

Comment: The underlying software to palimpsest, `udisks`, is no longer a separate project.  How does one now get benchmark information from the command line?

Comment: @tudor: I [updated my answer](https://superuser.com/posts/443214/revisions) with command line benchmarking options for Linux.

Comment: The link HDD Guardian is not working anymore and I can't seem to find the program anywhere. Strange.

Comment: @Christoph: That project was hosted on CodePlex, [which has shut down](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/03/31/shutting-down-codeplex/).  Looks like the project is no longer maintained.  You can use [GSmartControl](http://gsmartcontrol.sf.net) as an alternative to HDD Guardian.

Answer (score 3):

Another way you can test within Windows is to run the Command Prompt (Run as Administrator in Vista or Windows 7). From there, type `CHKDSK C: /f /r` and press Enter. This will scan the file system, and the free space for errors

Comment: ... and might cause data loss on a drive that is seriously damaged, as writing to damaged sectors will eat up the reserved reallocation sectors and then finally lead to write errors. So don't do this if you are unsure about the disk's health or have valuable data on it and no backup available. S.M.A.R.T. data or diagnostic tests however are read only and should not hurt. If there are problems reported, data should be backed up immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Check your drives S.M.A.R.T. status with a tool like [GSmartControl](http://gsmartcontrol.berlios.de/). If there are serious problems like defective sectors, these are probably visible in the data. You can also launch a self-test to find out about new errors, that haven't been logged yet.