# Windows 7 computer hangs for a few seconds very frequently; disk I/O light stays on turing freezes

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, freeze

Just recently, my Windows 7 computer (Thinkpad T410s) is suddenly doing a lot more disk I/O (as indicated by a light on the case) and randomly freezes for a couple seconds at a time before resuming whatever I was doing. The disk I/O light on my laptop stays solid on while the computer hangs (not flickering, like usual).

- I have run a CHKDSK on both my drives, no problems.
- Did a full scan with Microsoft Security Essentials, no viruses
- Checked the ram with Window's built in memory checker (forget the name), no warnings
- Did a full test on hardware with Lenovo's ThinkVantage hardware test software, no issues
- Checked the event log, nothing stuck out as out of the ordinary
- Updated all the drivers (and bios) to the latest version
- Emptied disks so they are less than 50% full
- Did a factory reset of the system, problem still exists
- <s>Cannot reproduce problem in safe-mode</s> <-- problem now exists in safe-mode

This is especially weird, since after the factory reset, the problem still exists. I was wondering if anybody has any insight as to what this might be; I'm stumped.

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Suspect hard drive is my first guess. If you can, try swapping the drive and see if there's a change in behaviour.

Comment: Would CHKDSK (HD Tune, or similar) detect faulty hard drives? I will test another hard drive as soon as I can, though it may be hard, as 1/8" HDDs are not very commonplace.

Comment: I've the exact symptoms and tests... My only one solution was intall Windows 8, the PC was absurdly fast!

Comment: Super User answer to diagnosing possible HDD problems: [http://superuser.com/a/443214](http://superuser.com/a/443214/83694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you download a disk checking utility such as the [free Acronis version.](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/drive-monitor/) This will at least hopefully narrow down any issues with the hard drive.

Comment: Thanks for showing me this tool. It says my boot disk's health is at 20%, the reallocated sectors count failed at 91 (raw: 198), and the reallocation event count is degrading at 100 (raw: 31). Do these warnings indicate a drive failure, and is the problem I am running into characteristic of a drive failure? Many thanks for your time.

Comment: The HD is $%^&! Back up, test the back up, and then bin it!

Comment: I've purchased a new SSD as a replacement. Worked great setting Windows up, but now the computer freezes for almost a minute at a time (though at further apart intervals). I will run Acronis again and post the results.

Comment: It says my brand new SSD is at 80% health (Soft read error degrading). Should my drive be at such low health (threshold for warning is 70%) if it's brand new?

Comment: I can mark an answer, though I don't believe this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If its at 20% the hard drive is going fail very soon . Get a new hard drive now , and backup all your files( you can use a hard drive dock for this) .

Reinstall the OS on a new hard drive and you should be good .

Comment: Yes, I've ordered a new drive (mSATA SSD with 1.8" adapter) and will post and update when it comes.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [latest Intel Rapid Storage driver](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=21730), as this is often a cause.

Comment: That assumes the OP actually has a version of that installed. Unless he is doing windows fake RAID via the BIOS there is no reason to assume this.

Comment: It turns out the AHCI controller was broken (breaking?). Running a linux distribution under compatibility mode for the hard drive controller does not have the same issue (Windows will not run in compatibility mode)