# Windows 7 computer hangs for minutes at a time, brand new SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd, freeze

As a solution to a previous issue I had ([Windows 7 computer hangs for a few seconds very frequently; disk I/O light stays on turing freezes](https://superuser.com/questions/457058/windows-7-computer-hangs-for-a-few-seconds-very-frequently-disk-i-o-light-stays)), I replaced my presumed failing HDD with a brand new SSD (a mSATA chip inside a 1.8" adapter). During set-up, the computer ran normally, but now it hangs for minutes at a time randomly (I can't find a reliable way to reproduce this, usually happens when I initiate disk I/O, though). The disk I/O light remains solid on while the computer is frozen.

I used [Acronis Drive Monitor](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/drive-monitor/) and found that the new SSD has a "soft read error rate" of over 6 million (and increasing). After some quick searching, I learned that this is characteristic of a drive that is failing.

My computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad T410s, and I'm up to day with Windows Update, as well as with Lenovo's Thinkvantage System Update (drivers). My SSD is an OCZ Nocti series mSATA SSD.

Any thoughts? Many thanks for your time.

**UPDATE:** The soft read error rate is increasing about every minute.

Comment: I think your laptop is eating hard drives. Test your motherboard and the power supply / battery.

Comment: Can you confirm when you wrote "I used Acronis Drive Monitor and found that the new SSD has a "soft read error rate" of over 6 million (and increasing). After some quick searching, I learned that this is characteristic of a drive that is failing." you are referring to the NEW hard drive?

Comment: Also, confirm that since you're using a new HDD, you are on a fresh installtion of Windows 7?

Comment: I'm confirming that the brand new SSD has a "soft read error rate" that resets to zero every time I boot up and increases as a very rapid rate (I've seen it reach as high as 150 million). The installation on the SSD is a "factory reset" provided by Lenovo's data reset DVDs.

Comment: have you tried the system tests available with Thinkvantage? Seems like there is a problem with something else than the disc

Comment: I've tried all the tests available with ThinkVantage, on my previous installation, as well as a fresh installation. There were no problems reported in either environment. I think there is a problem with the hard drive controller, as Windows, running AHCI mode freezes, but linux, running in compatibility mode, does not.

Comment: When you say it's a new install, did this issue happen on a vanilla installation or did you install other products (Office, Anti Virus, Games etc)?