# 100% disk usage, 100% of the time on Windows 8 with an SSD

Tags: performance

I have a should-be decent spec Laptop (Pentium Dual Core (one of the more recent ones), 8GB DDR3 Ram, SSD, Windows 8) but it is running horribly and the disk IO is always at either 99% or 100%, not [occasionally](https://superuser.com/questions/507930/windows-8-100-disk-active-time-no-actual-data-transferred) but always.

[image: Screenshot]

I installed the OS myself, and afterwards downloaded and installed all of the recommended drivers from the manufacturers website.

Is there anything obvious that would cause this?

Comment: Try running `resmon`, it sometimes provides more details.  It should let you sort the processes by I/O operations per second rather than throughput.

Comment: Also good tools you could use are XperfViewer or even better Windows Performance Analyzer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162931.aspx

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2009/08/17/xperf-to-investigate-slow-i-o-issues.aspx

Comment: I see that one of the `svchost` instances is sucking 1Mbps of network bandwidth. That’s not Windows Update is it? If so, it could be taking an inventory of your system which will cause the drive-access to spike for quite a while, yet show little activity because it’s a system process. If it’s not Windows Update (try stopping the *Windows Update*, *BITS*, and *Windows Installer Module* services), then it could be something else, so check if you have any unexpected network activity.

Comment: I have a working solution that worked for me here. https://superuser.com/a/1332999/53724

Answer (score 2):

I been investigating this issue for the last month, I have no definitive answer yet, but I know what is not, is not a program reading or writing to the disk, it will not show up in any diagnostic tools I try them all, is a bug, it changes in his behavior depending on the disk drivers (original Microsoft = more stable, take more time to start bugging or failing, and Intel or Adata drivers, less time to fail even after boot) any intensive IO can trigger the bug, my recommendation for now is to Uninstall any disk or chipset drivers by Intel or SATA/Ide drivers by secondary click in the device and Uninstall (choose delete drivers) this will buy you some time, In my case the computer now fails after a day or two of continuous usage.

This issue started after Microsoft update several system files in Windows 8 and install a priority update: Intel driver update for Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
Download size: 71 KB

Everyone recommends tools to look for the wild program or process, witch is the right first step, but there is none.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and keep us posted if you find anything! I'm using Linux exclusively atm at home (learning C++) and it runs amazingly well with an SSD but sure I will be back on Windows at some point!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I enabled AHCI on the BIOS (disable IDE emulation). If you do this Windows won´t start. To solve this, do on CMD as Administrator

```
bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal
```

then restart the computer, change BIOS and when Windows restarts in safe mode,  execute

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot
```

The next restart the problem should be solved.

Comment: I'm not on Windows, so maybe Windows users understand, but just in case: is the `{current}` part to be typed just like that, or should it be replaced with some some other value? (It looks a bit like a placeholder/variable to me?)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

Download the Intel Chipset Driver here:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=20775

It will decrease disk usage and bring it back down to a low amount.

I think the problem was caused by inadequate intel chip driver.