# Windos 10 Task Manager's Disk percentage suddenly jumps to 100% with no warning; I've already tried all the usual solutions

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, task-manager

Good evening; I've been having a problem with the Disk percentage seen in Task Manager, which jumps to 90-100% constantly for no reason. I've already tried to vanilla solutions: disabling Superfetch and Windows Search, clearing the temp folder and virtual memory, changing settings on Chrome and ran an anti-virus. The HDD health checks also say my HDD is healthy. Any idea on what would it be?

Comment: [replace HDD with SSD and your issue will be gone](https://superuser.com/a/1184894/174557)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it has something to do with Windows itself. I as well had this same problem SSD HD reading 100% usage. I googled and googled and finally was able to fix it. Reading so much up on this I've seen various things have helped different people. If I remember correctly my own problem was fixed with a driver update. Here is what some other found worked maybe it'll work for you too.
"What fixed it for me is going to settings, system, notifications, and turning off "show me tips about Windows." I believe that was the one causing problems, though I turned all of them off besides the app notifications. System processes went back down after a restart and haven't spiked since."