# Windows 10 runs slow and freezes. Almost always 100% disk usage

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance, freeze

My computer freezes often when booting and while it's working it functions very slowly. Cpu usage is almost always very low (3-30%), memory usage is very consistent (60-80%), but disk usage is almost always 100%.

My main drive is a ST100DM003 HDD. I've run chkdsk and it found no problems. I've run CrystalDiskInfo and it says everything is fine. I've run SeaTools and every test seemed to pass (except for one while I was defragging, but I think that was a fluke because I ran it again after the defragging finished and there were no problems). I also ran CrystalDiskMark, and the results are below.

---

### CrystalDiskMark 5.2.2 x64 (UWP) (C) 2007-2017 hiyohiyo

- MB/s = 1,000,000 bytes/s [SATA/600 = 600,000,000 bytes/s]
- KB = 1000 bytes, KiB = 1024 bytes

  Sequential Read (Q= 32,T= 1) :    30.303 MB/s

  Sequential Write (Q= 32,T= 1) :    16.670 MB/s

  Random Read 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :     0.606 MB/s [   147.9 IOPS]

  Random Write 4KiB (Q= 32,T= 1) :     0.375 MB/s [    91.6 IOPS]

  Sequential Read (T= 1) :    32.929 MB/s

  Sequential Write (T= 1) :    20.340 MB/s

  Random Read 4KiB (Q= 1,T= 1) :     0.321 MB/s [    78.4 IOPS]

  Random Write 4KiB (Q= 1,T= 1) :     0.444 MB/s [   108.4 IOPS]
- Test : 1024 MiB [C: 35.1% (325.3/926.1 GiB)] (x5)  [Interval=5 sec]
- Date : 2017/08/12 18:48:37
- OS : Windows 10  [10.0 Build 15063] (x64)

Comment: How much ram do you have? It may be reporting only 60~80% used but Windows may be prioritising disk cache over having programs and their data in ram. Personally these days I find that 8GB is just not enough. Also your disk sequential read and sequential write is quite low, how old is the disk, how full, how fragmented is it, and how many sector reallocations and pending sector reallocations are there? see the disk SMART data with a tool like http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/ for the sector reallocaton info

Comment: I have 16GB of RAM. The disk is about 2-3 years old. Windows reports 6% fragmentation. The disk is 35% full. GsmartControl reports 100 norm-ed and 0 raw in relocated sector count and 100 norm-ed and 0 raw in pending sector count.

Answer (score 0):

There's no just one cause that can result to your issue, it can be **driver-related** that is, `A faulty or outdated driver can lead to a Memory leak`.

This you can solve by:

> Right click the Start > System > On the left panel click **advanced system settings** > click on **Hardware** tab > **Device installation settings** > **Select No**, let me choose what to do, **"*Never install driver software from Windows update"***, leave the last box checked.

---

Next, there might be some programs that start themselves the moment you power on your computer. 
This you can solve by:

#### Disable Programs Running at Startup

It's suggested that you'd better disable as many programs as possible that are running at startup on Windows 10. This helps to save lots of CPU memory usage.

> *Press the **Windows key** and **R** at the same time.
>
> *Type **msconfig** in the run window and hit **Enter** of the keyboard.
>
> *The **Task manager** window pops up. Click on the **Startup** tab and you will see a list of programs that run at startup.
>
> *Right click on the applications that you don't want to run at startup and select **Disable**.

---

Your disk might be fragmented. And this occurs when a file is broken up into pieces to fit on the disk. When files are constantly being written, deleted and resized, they can result to fragmentation of your disk, which can slow PC performance,freeze-ups, long boot-times and random crashes.
This you can solve by:

#### Defragmenting your Hard Drives

> Press the **Windows key** and **R** at the same time.
>
> Type **dfrgui** in the run window and hit **Enter** of the keyboard.
>
> In the new window click on the hard drives you want to defragment.
>
> Click **Optimize** and follow the instructions on the screen to finish the defragment process.

---

You might have some errors on your disk.

#### Run Disk Check

> *Close all open programs and files.
>
> *Click **Start** > **File Explorer** > **This PC**.
>
> *Locate the **hard drive** you’d like to check, **right-click** on it and choose **Properties**.
>
> *Go to the **Tools** tab and click **Check**.
>
> *If your hard disk drive is problem-free, you’ll see this: ***Your drive was successfully scanned (Windows successfully scanned the drive. No errors were found.)***

---

Malwares can also result in this issue, you can solve this by:

#### Scan to Check Third Party Programs

> *Run a full system virus to scan on your Windows 10 computer to make sure that you don't have any third party programs that make your system RAM take up more usage.
>
> *Clear all your computer’s **temp** files.
>
> - On your keyboard, press **Windows key** and **R** at the same time,
> - In the Run form, type **temp** and hit Enter.

[image: temp files]

> - This will invoke **Windows Explorer** with your Temp folder open, showing you all the temp files on your computer.
> - Select all the files in the Temp folder and **delete** them.

---

You might have some corrupted files on your HDD;

#### Run System File Checker

> *Press the Windows key on your keyboard, then type **cmd** (DON’T press Enter). Windows will display a list of programs that match your search.
>
> *Right-click Command Prompt and choose **Run as administrator**.
>
> *If prompted to provide administrator permission, click **Yes**.
>
> *In the black Command Prompt window, type:
>
> ***sfc /scannow**
>
> *Then press Enter on your keyboard. 
>   Windows will scan your system for corrupted files, and attempt to fix any it finds. The results will display in this window, so please leave it open until the operation is complete.

After all these, you can then

> Reboot Your Computer

Sources : [Fix High CPU/RAM//Memory Usage](http://www.drivethelife.com/windows-10/fix-high-ram-cpu-memory-usage-after-windows-10-update.html) ,

[Windows 10 freezes randomly [Solved]](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-windows-10-freezes-locks-up-randomly-easily/)

Comment: the slow HDD is the cause of the ugly performance. use a SSD and windows is fast

Comment: It shouldn't be the driver because I am using the standard windows driver. I already disabled all unnecessary startup programs. I already tried defragging. I ran disk check and it said that there were no errors. I ran malwarebytes, adwcleaner, and junkware removal tool and none of them found anything of significance. I regularly run ccleaner to clear out temp files and others. And system file checker didn't find any "integrity violations"

Comment: I think you should go with what @magicandre1981 has posted on [https://superuser.com/questions/1182651/windows-10-100-disk-usage-after-startup], `For performance and stability reasons, use the SDD in the slot where the HDD was and use the HDD in the caddy.`

Comment: I guess that's what I'll have to do. I was just hoping to avoid spending another couple hundred dollars.

Comment: sometimes, we gotta pass through pain to enjoy peace. After doing that, let us know if your problem is fully resolve.

Comment: @Alex use the SSD for Windows + programs, here a 256GB SSD should be enough. Use the HDD for storing data