# Im getting 100% disk usage on only 1 of 2 disks

Tags: windows-10

I have windows 10 so i put in a second hard drive to try to aid with my 100% disk usage but noe it just has on at 100% and the new second one at 0% how do i get the two to work together?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer

Comment: DETAIL, give us more detail, please! Adding a hard drive would not resolve your issue (since the data the computer uses is not on that drive). Various possible causes: You are using an HDD with a slow rpm or slow read speed (try upgrading to a higher spec drive: preferably an SSD); A particular program or programs are using high disk usage (look under Task Manager Processes Tab and sort by disk usage to see what process is using it the most) - if you find this program, you may EDIT your question and specify which program is using up disk usage. Also, fix your grammar by editing the question.

Comment: Hard drives are like cars. Buying a second one and putting it in your garage doesn't make the first one faster.

Comment: replace the HDD with a SSD. The [HDDs are simply too slow](https://superuser.com/a/1184894/174557)

Answer (score 1):

Most (all?) OS's treat each drive individually by default, rather then spreading the data across them - thus in order to take advantage of your second drive you will need to move data from the first drive onto the second drive.

(There are alternatives for this like JBOD, RAID0, but these are pretty advanced solutions which will require "relatively expert" assistance)

Comment: * also, RAID0 and JBOD will increase the risk of data loss, as you have twice the hardware for the same files.

Comment: I think you're safe to safe to say "all" OSes leave it up to the admin to elect the purpose of a new drive. I can only think data loss would be in the future of a user with an OS that makes such sweeping changes "automatically."