# Is my disk faulty or is there a Windows 10 issue that could cause 100% disk activity with no throughput?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

Yesterday my secondary conventional HDD started acting weird. No throughput or even just a few KB and it'll lock at max disk activity.

Sometimes though I can transfer large files instantly but as of a couple days it's switching between 100% activity at idle and then allowing me to use the disk "normally" briefly before switching back to this odd behavior.

Given that the disk is a few years old, is the disk faulty? Or is this a software issue in Windows 10?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please can you share the "_Processes_" tab, sorted by the "_Disk_" column, with greatest at the top?

Comment: did you try chkdsk /R d:   See if you have bad sectors.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: use a [SSD to "solve" it](https://superuser.com/a/1184894/174557)

Answer (score 0):

HDD was mechanically b0rked. I installed a new drive and have had no problems since.