Computer with SSD slow after not being used for a period
I have this painful issue where I'm gone for holiday (1-2 weeks) and even for a weekend (barely 2 days) my PC gets really slow and I'm suspecting SSD.

Everything seems so slow despite boot being fast as usual. One more thing I noted is that when I copy a file during this "slow period" it usually ramps up to 80MB/s speed and then suddenly drops to less than 5MB/s and stays there for a while like frozen. I use Windows 11 so that could be another issue because MC keeps pushing its garbage software as seen in task manager screenshot 2. I don't use lightning fast SSD either, Adata SU630 I think, it's more than enough for me but I want it to run at average speeds because then there's no point in switching to NVME or something faster because the issue will persist.
Sometimes during this period it also takes painfully long to shut down but I figured out editing one registry value would make it shut down faster by not checking for all active/open programs and that improved shut down massively.

Is everything still slow if you boot into Safe Mode?

MC keeps pushing its garbage software as seen in task manager screenshot I see no MC garbage - what are you referring to specifically?

@JaromandaX I am referring to "Edge installer" and "Anti-malware service". Okay I expected that win defender starts its updates/scans but I definitely did not expect to see Edge installer and it taking 50% of drive performance at times. I don't even use Edge, I definitely didn't run it so it must be some sort of automated process.

One more thing I forgot to mention is that almost everything is turned off on startup so it has minimal impact on the performance, but as seen, it still happens.

You have a DRAM-less SSD, which is likely the cause of the slowdown when transferring large files. Your drive uses some of its QLC NAND flash to act in SLC mode to speed things up, but once it filled that SLC cache, performance will come down noticeably. If its then also doing +-50MB/sec of random read/writes in the background like in your screenshot, then you may well see a performance plummet like you describe. It's not really microsoft's fault and its temporary in nature by either the end of the background updates or the file copy.

It indeed is Microsoft's fault because what is "edge installer" supposed to be/do? I don't even use edge and that thing took well over 50% of resources before the screenshot was made. I disabled edge in every single way from startup to default browser but it still shows up... In other words I don't need another generic browser that doesn't even use google search engine in the first place and secondly has ai support which every half decent browser has nowadays. Linux in comparison is much more streamlined and faster but I can't be bothered with all the apps and integration.

Go use linux then. Under which your SSD will likely show similar behaviour copying very large files. No use in getting all worked up here about something else that isnt the issue.

Relevant. Note there is a whole ring of marked duplicates, and most of them seem to have various sorts of valuable information: https://superuser.com/questions/1182651/windows-10-100-disk-usage-after-startup

@DaniloJonić I would not be so quick to assume it is this one process you find frustrating that is the cause of the slowness you're observing. Also, please note that this is a professional site. While we understand that you find this situation frustrating, communication here is better when it remains professional and as calm as possible.

@JoepvanSteen 140GB out of 480GB is available, total terabytes written is 28, manufacturer claim is 800 so not even 5% of life cycle. I usually don't overload it, last 50-80GB is always free (10%-25% of the total capacity).

@JoepvanSteen I actually use manufacturer software, not sure if it does anything tho because it performs it in less than 5 seconds. https://ibb.co/LknK0My
