# Windows 7 (64 bits) on Lenovo L530 Constant 100% Highest Active Time

Tags: windows-7, disk-activity

My laptop became unresponsive recently. I searched for the root cause and I found out that my resource monitor shows 100 percent of Highest Active Time for the disk and not much i/o with it. The process causing this activity is mostly 'System' wit PID 4. But sometimes other stuff like 'svchost'. I tried new Intel chipset drivers, Matrix Storage, even a fresh install of Windows. Nothing helped. Any ideas?

Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try to remind what last did you do before this happened to your system? Also provide more info e.g.(when did it start, if there is any pauses, etc)

Comment: Well, I cannot definitely say when it has started. But it should not matter since I did a clean install today it still happens. I just need an idea to maybe prove if it is or it is not a hardware failure.

Comment: That folder which is active in your printscreen at system process is created by windows updates, have a look at windows update screen if there are some new updates or whether these are installing.

Comment: Of course I know updates are installing. The point is it just happened to be installing updates. Here the computer doesnt do anything at all: http://postimage.org/image/u9qakkw63/

Comment: No one can convince me this is normal. It is not. With a little I\O that much highest active time? I looked at other computers too. None of them has it.

Comment: Related post with lot many answers which can be tried - [Extremely high disk activity without any real usage](https://superuser.com/q/470334/374397)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem turned out to be an hardware issue. I replaced my Toshiba MK5061GSY drive with an older WD. The problem is gone. Thanks everyone for the comments.

Comment: I've exactly same problem with both Windows 10 as well as Windows 7 OS on my PC. I've a Dell laptop with Intel CORE i3 processor series. But when I run the Dell BIOS built-in diagnostics it shows no disk errors. Not sure why it is happening? Can the disk still be faulty even if the Dell tools are showing no errors?